# Cant run Selenium on Ubuntu with Python

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, geckodriver

I cant run or install selenium on Ubuntu 18.04.3 ...
I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@hoppy/how-to-test-or-scrape-javascript-rendered-websites-with-python-selenium-a-beginner-step-by-c137892216aa also with the digitalocean setup.

I tried different things...
I installed the geckodriver in /var/bin
in /var/local/bin
added both to PATH
tried with a path in the code and without
tried with firefox (preferred) ...
nothing helps

This Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver') # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Ends up with:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:: command not found
(venv) root@EtherScrape:/var/test# python /var/test/server_test.py              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/test/server_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver') # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=83.0.4103.61 (94f915a8d7c408b09cc7352161ad592299f384d2-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#561}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64)
```

This Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

With that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/test/server_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7ff3109ced68>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "/var/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Please help.
Tried many solutions so far but no one worked out...

Comment: What do you get if you run this command in a terminal? `which chromedriver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
```

Works for me at the chrome driver.